# Subquery to find employees with same job as the employee with name starting with J?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have to Create a query that lists the lastname, edlevel , job, the number of years they've worked as of Jan 01/2002 ( hint : year function Jan 01/2002 minus hiredate), and their salary.
Get the employees that have the same Job  as the employee named starts with J  (hint subquery from employee) and hiredate < Jan 01/2002  Sort the listing by highest salary first.

My query works other than getting the employees that have the same job as the employee named starts with J

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

[Sample of results from SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh3Fy.png)

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE FIRSTNME LIKE "J%";
```

[All results from SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE FIRSTNME LIKE "J%"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLPM0.png)

This is my query so far

```
    SELECT EMP.FIRSTNME,EMP.LASTNAME, EMP.EDLEVEL, EMP.JOB, 
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF("2002-01-01",EMP.HIREDATE) / 365) AS YearsWorked, 
    EMP.SALARY 
    FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
    WHERE EMP.HIREDATE < "2002-01-01" 
    AND (SELECT EMP2.JOB FROM EMPLOYEE EMP2 WHERE EMP2.FIRSTNME LIKE'J%') 
    ORDER BY EMP.SALARY DESC;
```

This query returns no results, if I remove the subquery it returns the results needed other than what I need from the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

just little fix will help

```
SELECT EMP.FIRSTNME, EMP.LASTNAME, EMP.EDLEVEL, EMP.JOB, 
FLOOR(DATEDIFF("2002-01-01",EMP.HIREDATE) / 365) AS YearsWorked, 
EMP.SALARY 
FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
WHERE EMP.HIREDATE < "2002-01-01" 
AND EMP.JOB in (SELECT EMP2.JOB FROM EMPLOYEE EMP2 WHERE EMP2.FIRSTNME LIKE'J%') 
ORDER BY EMP.SALARY DESC;
```

you have to use 'EMP.JOB in' in where before your subquery